# Delete * elements in nested XML by knowing attribute value

Tags: c#

Suppose I have the following XML :

```
<Chapter Name="Introduction" >
   <Overview caption="Simple" >
       <Property name="ElementID" value="1"  />
       <Property name="Summary" value="no"  />
       <Overview caption="Simple" >
           <Property name="ElementID" value="2"  />
       </Overview>
       <Property name="ElementID" value="37"  />
       <Property name="ElementID" value="38"  />
       <Property name="Summary" value="no"  />
   </Overview>  
   </Overview>
   </Overview>  
</Chapter>
```

I have tried :

```
 private static void RemoveNode(XElement root)
    {
        var query = root.Elements("Overview")
          .Where(p => p.Element("Overview").Element("Property").Attribute("name").Value == "ElementID")
          .Select(x => x.Nodes().ElementAt(0));
        //.Remove();
        query.Remove();
          if (query.Any())

        RemoveNode(root);
    }
```

I need to remove all nodes/elements has attribute [name] with  value ="ElementID" using C#

Comment: And what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Check your sample. The XML code is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Using LinqToXml

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("YourFile");

var q = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("Name") != null && "ElementID" == (string)x.Attribute("values"));

foreach (var item in q) item.Remove();

doc.Save("YourFile");
```

Comment: if you are using `(string)x.Attribute("values")` , you don't need to use `.Value`

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = root.Descendants()
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "ElementID")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach( (x) => x.RemoveAll());
root.Save(path);
```

Comment: ForEach && RemoveAll?

Comment: To remove selected elements, `"I need to remove all nodes/elements has attribute.."`

Comment: RemoveAll Not remove the element itself, only the descendants. use instead Remove

Comment: but still I have 

<Property />